# Format of sms text in Twilio api

Tags: sms, twilio

i am working on sms application with twilio api, i faced a problem about sms formatting

1) a string " i'm here" in php
this is going like this in sms body
i\'m here

i dont want that slash to come up in sms

2) i want to add line break in message how can i do that.

like this
Name age phone
Simer 23 2546181541
Mark 25 3521447821

Comment: I'll have an answer for you over on your post at our forums shortly: http://getsatisfaction.com/twilio/topics/format_of_sms_body_text

Comment: It looks like Twilio inserts this into the message body, after it's sent. Hopefully some day somebody will return here with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reply by Twilio staff:

If anyone else needs newlines, make sure your [PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) strings are double quoted instead of single quoted and the \n will work: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there's a [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) option that (while deprecated now) escapes certain characters in a POSTs and GETs.  You may be suffering from that.